# diagonalization of a matrix

Tags: matrices

I want to diagonalize this matrix :

$$
        A =\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

**the first step I did is calculates the eigenvalues​​ :**

$$det(A-λ I_3)=0\iff \begin{vmatrix}
        -λ & -1 & 0 \\
        -1 & -λ & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 1-λ \\
        \end{vmatrix} = 0$$

$$\iff-λ\begin{vmatrix}
        -λ & 0  \\
        1 & 1-λ  \\
        \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}
        -1 & 0  \\
        1 & 1-λ  \\
        \end{vmatrix} = 0$$

$$\iff -λ³ + λ² + λ - 1 = 0$$

$$\iff -λ²(λ-1) + λ - 1 = 0$$
$$\iff (λ-1)(-λ²+1)= 0$$
$$\iff (1-\lambda^2)= 0  \quad\text{or}\quad  (λ-1)=0$$
$$l_1 = l_2 = 1\quad; \quad  l_3=-1$$

**Then the second step is to calculate the eigenvectors :**

but I don't know how to do this step , could you please tell me what is the method to do it ?

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192801/understanding-the-process-of-finding-eigenvectors

Comment: @vadim123 I cant understand the step where he is reduce the matrix to row-eschelon

Comment: How did you get these eigenvalues to be zero, your equation suggests 1,1,-1

Comment: @imranfat I cant understand you the eigenvalues I got are : `l1, l2 and l3 <=> 1,1,-1`

Comment: I see it, didn't read it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solve the system of equations $(A-\lambda I_3)X=0$ where 
$$
        X =\begin{pmatrix}
        x\\y\\z
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$

For $\lambda=-1$ we find 
$$ v_1 =\begin{pmatrix}
        -1\\-1\\1
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
and for $\lambda=1$ we find
 $$v_2=\begin{pmatrix}
        0\\0\\1
        \end{pmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad v_3 =\begin{pmatrix}
        -1\\1\\0
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: for λ=−1, okey I understood it, but for the second case λ=1 wehn I solve the system $$(A-I_3)X = 0$$ I found `x' + x'' = 0`.

but how did you find the v2 and the v3 ?

Comment: @AimadMajdou You find $x+y=0$ so you can choose $z$ arbitrary and $x=-y$ and then you can find two linearly independant vectors $v_2$ and $v_3$ as in my answer that satisfy this condition.

Comment: so as I think from to x +y= 0 => y =-x so v3=(1,-1,0) so why you choosed the other solution and not (1,-1,0) ?

I didn't understand why z =1 in v2 from x+y=0 => z =0 not 1.

Comment: @AimadMajdou There are many possibilies to choose $v_2$ and $v_3$ but the important  thing is that these vectors must be linearly independant  since $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ must form a basis, hence the aim of the choice  $z=0$ and $z=1$ in the two vectors is to ensure the independance of $v_2$ and $v_3$.

Comment: what do you mean by  linearly independant ?